# Doesn't go to single post page

Tags: php, wordpress

Created Custom Post Type. The page template for each post is single-speaker.php. But when creating a post and going to its page, it goes to the main page. Can't see page template. And the condition does not work -if(is_singular( 'speaker' )). How can this be fixed?

```js
// create post type

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'speaker', 
      array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Speakers' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'speaker' )
      ),
       'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'speaker' ),
      )
  );
    
  register_post_type( 'sessions', 
      array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Sessions' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'sessions' )
      ),
       'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
      )
  );    
    
  register_taxonomy(
  'positions',
  'speaker',
      array(
      'label' => ( 'Positions' ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      )
  );
    
  register_taxonomy(
  'countries',
  'speaker',
      array(
      'label' => ( 'Countries' ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 1):

- What you can do first, is to install Query Monitor to check the templates you're landing on and which conditional tags you can use to call this specific template
- Try using is_single('speaker') instead
- And last, check your loop. Are you calling the main loop or a custom loop for the speaker template

I hope this helps!